# Stacking absolute elements with transform

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-transforms

I'm currently building a form with a custom absolutely positioned dropdown. The other input fields are animated in using `transform: translateY`. However I simply can't get the dropdown to stack on top of the below input elements. I've simplified my problem to the following:

html:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a top">
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

css:

```
.a {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    position: "relative";
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.b {
    position: "absolute";
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:25px;
    background: blue;
}
.input.top {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The following fiddle illustrates my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/m817ffqy/1/

I've experimented with `transform-style: flat` and setting `translateZ`, but I've not been able to get the desired effect..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
position: "relative";
position: "absolute";
```

try:

```
position: relative;
position: absolute;
```

Also, `.input.top` will need either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`.

Comment: Although you are correct with the syntax, it doesn't seem to make a difference in the demo. Also, `.input.top` doesn't work because there is no `.input` class in the HTML. Plus, all elements are `relative` or `absolute` already.